# Error with converting keras graph model to tf.js

Tags: keras, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to convert a non-sequential keras .h5 model to tensorflow.js, but some weird things are happening.

Running the tensorflowjs_converter in the command line converts it fine, but when I look into model.json, I see that it says

"format": "layers-model"

Why is it doing this? Shouldn't a non-sequential model be converted into a graph model?

Comment: Do you have an issue in loading the `model.json`?

Comment: @edkeveked I'm currently having a separate issue, so I can't 100% say for certain, but loading the model gives me an error only for the separate issue, not the format of the model

Comment: Could you possibly add relevant part of the error to the question?

Comment: @edkeveked I'm not sure what you mean. The error is unrelated to the graph vs. layer model problem, so there are no relevant parts

Comment: I am not sure either what you meant by the separate issue. That is why I asked to put the error in the question

Comment: @edkeveked I fixed the unrelated error, and now am having an error that I believe is related to this. I've created a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62111983/unhandled-promise-rejection-typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating