# [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'x.mul')]

Tags: react-native, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to get a pre-trained model loaded onto react native.

When I try to run it, it gives me the error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'x.mul')]
```

Here is my code:

```
const TensorCamera = cameraWithTensors(Camera);

const modelJson = require('../../assets/model/model-fixed.json');
const modelWeights = require('../../assets/model/group1-shard1of1.bin');

class CameraCompo extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { modelLoaded: false };
    this.isModelLoaded = this.isModelLoaded.bind(this);
    this.getModel = this.getModel.bind(this);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await tf.ready()
    console.log("TF Ready")
    this.model = await tf.loadLayersModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelWeights));
    console.log("Model Loaded")
    this.setState({modelLoaded:true})
  }

  isModelLoaded(){
    return this.state.modelLoaded;
  }

  getModel(){
    return this.model
  }

  handleCameraStream(images, updatePreview, gl) {
    model2 = this.getModel()
    console.log(model2)
    const loop = async () => {
      const nextImageTensor = images.next().value
      const nextImageTensor2 = nextImageTensor.reshape([1,320,320,3])

      //console.log("Prediction:")
      if (this.isModelLoaded()) {
        if (model2 == undefined){
          model2 = this.getModel()
        }
        else{
        console.log(nextImageTensor2)
        console.log(model2)
        const prediction = (await model2.predict(nextImageTensor2))[0];
        console.log(prediction)
        }
      }


      //
      // do something with tensor here
      //

      // if autorender is false you need the following two lines.
      // updatePreview();
      // gl.endFrameEXP();

      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    loop();
  }

  render() {
    // Currently expo does not support automatically determining the
    // resolution of the camera texture used. So it must be determined
    // empirically for the supported devices and preview size.

    let textureDims;
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      textureDims = {
        height: 1920,
        width: 1080,
      };
    } else {
      textureDims = {
        height: 1200,
        width: 1600,
      };
    }

    return <View>
      <TensorCamera
        // Standard Camera props
        style={CameraStyle.preview}
        type={Camera.Constants.Type.front}
        isModelLoaded={this.isModelLoaded}
        getModel = {this.getModel}
        // Tensor related props
        cameraTextureHeight={textureDims.height}
        cameraTextureWidth={textureDims.width}
        resizeHeight={320}
        resizeWidth={320}
        resizeDepth={3}
        onReady={this.handleCameraStream}
        autorender={true}
      />
    </View>
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
```

The error occurs on the line:

```
const prediction = (await model2.predict(nextImageTensor2))[0];
```

But the two lines before

```
console.log(nextImageTensor2)
console.log(model2)
```

both return seemingly normal things.

One thing to note is that my model should be a graph model (it isn't sequential), but my model.json says it is a layers-model.

Link to python model: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ginejkhna1sic8/unet_70.h5?dl=0

Link to Tf.js model: 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/p9ddj0vee4vrd9j/AAB5uU2EFIGr21A0_zzj3XcQa?dl=0

Model Summary:
https://pastebin.com/iUrhuxJq

To verify that the model is a graph model, look to "block1a_se_excite"

Command line used to convert: tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=keras --quantization_bytes=1 --weight_shard_size_bytes=9999999999999 ~/PycharmProjects/TrueSky/models/unet_70.h5 ~/PycharmProjects/TrueSky/models/tfjs_model

Comment: You are not using `tf.mul` in the snippet of the question. So maybe that the error is related the model definition . Could you please add your python model to the question ?

Comment: @edkeveked Added

Comment: Is it possible to share the python code instead of the .h5 file? Additionnally, it will be best to see what command line you are using to convert it to js

Comment: @edkeveked Added the command line. How do you want me to share the python code? If you mean the building of the model, I used an architecture provided by a library. Would the model summary be sufficient?

Comment: I think that you need to use `tf.loadGraphModel` instead of `tf.loadLayersModel`

Comment: @edkeveked tf.LoadGraphModel doesn't work, as model-fixed.json stores the model as "layers-model"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215154/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-alex).